# Remember to call close() on all Realm instances even though I call close()

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm seeing

```
Remember to call close() on all Realm instances. Realm /data/data/com.org.example/files/default.realm is being finalized without being closed, this can lead to running out of native memory.
```

even though I've clearly called `.close()` after every call of `getInstance(realmConfig)`.

Most of the time it looks like this:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
try {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(someData);
    realm.commitTransaction();
} catch (Exception e) {
    realm.cancelTransaction();
} finally {
    if (realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

And other times it looks like (using Rx Observable Pattern):

```
@Override
public void call(Subscriber<? super JsonElement> subscriber) {
    SomeJson someJson = Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfig).where(SomeJson.class)
                    .equalTo("type", type)
                    .equalTo("id", id)
                    .findFirst();

    if (someJson == null || !someJson.isDataValid()) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "Did not find value for id: " + id + " for type: " + type);
        subscriber.onNext(null);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
        Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfig).close();
        return;
    }

    JsonElement val = (new JsonParser()).parse(someJson.jsonString);
    subscriber.onNext(val);
    subscriber.onCompleted();
    Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfig).close();
}
```

Any idea why I'm getting these warnings still?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfig);
// ...
Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfig).close();
```

The problem is here. You have acquired *another* `Realm`, and closed it, but you haven't closed the orignal `realm`.

You should use try-with-resources for all this:

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig)) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(someData);
    realm.commitTransaction();
} catch (Exception e) {
    realm.cancelTransaction();
}
```

[Note that `realm` could never be null at the point you were testing it, and if it was it would have triggered an NPE much further up.]

and

```
@Override
public void call(Subscriber<? super JsonElement> subscriber) {
    try (Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfig)) {
        SomeJson someJson = realm.where(SomeJson.class)
                    .equalTo("type", type)
                    .equalTo("id", id)
                    .findFirst();

        if (someJson == null || !someJson.isDataValid()) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "Did not find value for id: " + id + " for type: " + type);
            subscriber.onNext(null);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
            return;
        }

        JsonElement val = (new JsonParser()).parse(someJson.jsonString);
        subscriber.onNext(val);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try this now.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to have a single member variable referencing a Realm and just re-use that? Or do I have to always call getInstance before querying or writing?

Comment: Sigh. *Of course* you can store it in a variable: why not? and calling `getInstance()` every time is the *problem* here, not the solution.

Comment: I guess what I'm confused about is if I don't call getInstance() will the realm be open?

Comment: @clu Sigh sigh. The Realm stays open until you close it. There is nothing extraordinary about this. Calling `getInstance()` when you already have one is pointless, and calling it just to close it doesn't begin to make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Every time you call `Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfig)`, a local reference to this `Realm` instance is created in the current Thread.

You need to call `close()` on all references in order to really close the `Realm` instance.

In your Rx implementation you call `Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfig)` three times, therefore creating three local references, two of which are closed.

You could create a single reference and close it once and for all (just like you do in the first code snippet)

```
@Override
public void call(Subscriber<? super JsonElement> subscriber) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfig);
    SomeJson someJson = realm.where(SomeJson.class)
                    .equalTo("type", type)
                    .equalTo("id", id)
                    .findFirst();

    if (someJson == null || !someJson.isDataValid()) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "Did not find value for id: " + id + " for type: " + type);
        subscriber.onNext(null);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
        realm.close();
        return;
    }

    JsonElement val = (new JsonParser()).parse(someJson.jsonString);
    subscriber.onNext(val);
    subscriber.onCompleted();
    realm.close();
}
```